# What if potential difference is 0 in photoelectric effect? And what would happen as it goes negative?

Tags: potential, atomic-physics, voltage, photoelectric-effect

I'm confused as to why potential difference in itself is not sufficient to move electrons and there is a certain kinetic energy required to move the electron

Answer (score 2):

If potential difference is zero then there still be photocurrent because the electrons have Kinetic Energy.

If the potential goes negative then there still be photocurrent but after increasing the negative potential then at some potential there will be no photocurrent because that potential will be the stopping potential.[image]